# Re-route backend routes between containers within the same host

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Hi I'm new to docker containers. I have the following setup:

The docker host is running on a Linux server, it is running 4 apps:

1. reverse-proxy (nodejs-based)
2. frontend container
3. backend container
4. active mq container

All of them are running in **my-network**

Here is the problem, I would like to re-route every urls that come into the reverse-proxy to where it suppose to be. And restriction is I can't use re-write the reverse-proxy, because it is not worthy to re-write

The following are the **docker-compose.yml** files

```
version: '3'
services:
  backend:
    image: tomcat/test:first
    ports:
     - "8080:8080"
    networks:
     - my-network
    volumes:
     - "/home/lluo/app/myApp/target/MyApp/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/config:/usr/local/tomcat/conf/myApp-configuration/"
    depends_on:
     - active_mq
  active_mq:
    image: active_mq/test:first
    ports:
     - "24043:24043"
    networks:
     - my-network
networks:
 my-network:
  external: true


version: '3'
services:
  reverse_proxy:
    container_name: proxy_container
    image: reverse/proxy:docker
    ports:
     - "0.0.0.0:15009:15009"
    networks:
     - my-network
networks:
  my-network:
    external: true


version: '3'
services:
  frontend:
    image: template/frontend:after_merge_develop
    container_name: fe_container
    ports:
     - "3000:3000"
    networks:
     - my-network
    volumes:
     - "/home/lluo/config.json:/app/dist/config.json"
networks:
  my-network:
    external: true
```

And I bind the network ipv4_address to be 0.0.0.0

Please help me resolve this issue, it's been days.
Thank you very much!

Comment: The "ports" directive works with this syntax? I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yes I have 3 containers running and each of them is running on `0.0.0.0` but not the same port. In my VM it is showing me correct(ie: `0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp`)